# From Topoi to Grothendieck categories

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, topos-theory, abelian-categories, locally-presentable-categories

This question is mostly about a reference request. Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a Grothendieck topos. I am looking for a reference of the following two facts. I am aware that $(2) \Rightarrow (1)$ by Gabriel-Popescu. I was sure I had seen $(1)$ in Bourceux's encyclopedia, but I can't find it anymore.

1. The category of internal abelian group objects $\mathsf{Ab}(\mathcal{E})$ is a Grothendieck category.
2. Call $\mathsf{Set}[\mathsf{Ab}]$ the classifying topos of abelian groups, and let $\mathcal{E} \simeq \mathsf{Sh}(C,J)$. Then $$\mathsf{Ab}(\mathcal{E}) \simeq \mathsf{Cocontlex(\mathsf{Set}[\mathsf{Ab}], \mathcal{E})} \simeq \mathsf{lex}(\mathsf{Ab}_\omega,\mathcal{E}) \simeq \mathsf{lex}(\mathsf{Ab}_\omega,\mathsf{Sh}(C,J)) \simeq \mathsf{Sh}(C,\mathsf{Ab}).$$

Comment: I don't understand which part of (2) is non-trivial ? The equivalence between the first and the last is pretty obvious if you just write what it means to be an abelian group in Sh(C,J) vs a sheaf of abelian group (it works for any algebraic theory)

Comment: @SimonHenry, I agree with you. I was asking because I might want to cite it.

Comment: Like @SimonHenry says, the equivalence between the first and last of (2) holds for any algebraic theory and, if I am not mistaken, appears as Proposition 6.3.1 in SGA 4 (although of course they do not use the terminology "algebraic theory").  But maybe you are looking for a reference mentioning the whole chain of equivalences?  For what concerns (1), again I may be mistaken but I think it is (a special case of) Proposition 6.7 of SGA 4.

Answer (score 9):

Johnstone's "Topos theory" has a chapter on cohomology; your (1) is the first result the author proves. I don't remember about (2), but maybe it's also there?

Comment: Thanks. $(1)$ is Thm. 8.11 in Topos Theory. (2) does not seems to be there.